# How to successfully install ubergraph

Tags: clojure

First I have to say, I'm completely new to clojure, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.
I recently installed the clojure package on the atom text editor in order to create some graphs and tried to add ubergraph, an extension that makes weighted graphs possible, since these are not supported in the standard clojure package.

I followed the quickstart guide on ubergraphs github https://github.com/Engelberg/ubergraph and managed to complete the first step (adding ubergraph to leiningen dependencies). I downloaded the git repository and don't know how to carry on from here. Running the example code

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [ubergraph.core :as uber]))

(def graph1
  (uber/graph [:a :b] [:a :c] [:b :d]))
```

on the repl as described on github ends up with the following error:

CompilerException java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(ubergraph/core.clj:11:1)

The line that seems to cause the error in core.clj is:

```
(import-vars
 [...])
```

I skipped over the vars since I don't think they're causing the problem.
Clojure runs on the correct version (1.9.0) and java 8 is installed. Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I just installed the library, created a fresh namespace, pasted the code you have above in, and it worked. It works for both 1.9.0 and 1.10.0 for me. Try running `lein clean`.

Comment: Tried it out, didn't work. Still returns the same error. Could you post the code you used to create the namespace? Also, do I have to put the lib somewhere specific? I might be doing something wrong there. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried running it 1.10.0, and got pretty much the same thing:
`(ns example.core
  (:require [ubergraph.core :as uber]))
Unexpected error (NullPointerException) macroexpanding potemkin.namespaces/import-def at (core.clj:11:1)`

Comment: `Running the example code on the repl` - which command are you using?

Comment: It's described right below, the one trying to create the namespace.

Comment: Hello! Can you consider trying to install and use a different library? Then you can figure out whether there is a problem with `ubergraph`, or whether you just need to learn how to install libraries. After that, it will be simpler to help :)

Comment: Alright, will do, but I need to get some sleep first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment "Also, do I have to put the lib somewhere specific?", this seems to caused by a misunderstanding of how to install a library. You shouldn't be manually dealing with stuff like that; leiningen handles library installation for you.

Here's a quick guide that assumes you haven't created a project yet. If you have, skip to step 2.

1. Run `lein new app you-project-name-here`. This will create a barebones project with a `project.clj` and basic file structure. If you use an IDE like IntelliJ+Cursive, creating a new project will do this step automatically.
2. Go into your `project.clj`, and add `[ubergraph "0.5.2"]` to the `:dependencies` entry. As a minimal, reduced example, it should look something like:

   ```
   (defproject example "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
       :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                      [ubergraph "0.5.2"]]

       :main example.core) ; The path to your core
   ```
3. Have your `core` as something like:

   ```
   (ns example.core
     (:require [ubergraph.core :as uber])
     (:gen-class))

   (def graph1
     (uber/graph [:a :b] [:a :c] [:b :d]))

   (defn -main
     "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
     [& args]
     (println "The graph:" graph1))
   ```
4. Now run `lein run`. You should see it download the dependencies, then print something like this mess:

   ```
   The graph: {:node-map {:a #ubergraph.core.NodeInfo{:out-edges {:b #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "0768ef5b-1507-4bb0-b3da-fc14a84d013d", :src :a, :dest :b, :mirror? false}}, :c #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "acddd770-52cc-4b1f-aec1-762861e70ee2", :src :a, :dest :c, :mirror? false}}}, :in-edges {:b #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "0768ef5b-1507-4bb0-b3da-fc14a84d013d", :src :b, :dest :a, :mirror? true}}, :c #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "acddd770-52cc-4b1f-aec1-762861e70ee2", :src :c, :dest :a, :mirror? true}}}, :out-degree 2, :in-degree 2}, :b #ubergraph.core.NodeInfo{:out-edges {:a #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "0768ef5b-1507-4bb0-b3da-fc14a84d013d", :src :b, :dest :a, :mirror? true}}, :d #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "ef931d4e-8143-4cd1-8a10-c3692c47072f", :src :b, :dest :d, :mirror? false}}}, :in-edges {:a #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "0768ef5b-1507-4bb0-b3da-fc14a84d013d", :src :a, :dest :b, :mirror? false}}, :d #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "ef931d4e-8143-4cd1-8a10-c3692c47072f", :src :d, :dest :b, :mirror? true}}}, :out-degree 2, :in-degree 2}, :c #ubergraph.core.NodeInfo{:out-edges {:a #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "acddd770-52cc-4b1f-aec1-762861e70ee2", :src :c, :dest :a, :mirror? true}}}, :in-edges {:a #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "acddd770-52cc-4b1f-aec1-762861e70ee2", :src :a, :dest :c, :mirror? false}}}, :out-degree 1, :in-degree 1}, :d #ubergraph.core.NodeInfo{:out-edges {:b #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "ef931d4e-8143-4cd1-8a10-c3692c47072f", :src :d, :dest :b, :mirror? true}}}, :in-edges {:b #{#ubergraph.core.UndirectedEdge{:id #uuid "ef931d4e-8143-4cd1-8a10-c3692c47072f", :src :b, :dest :d, :mirror? false}}}, :out-degree 1, :in-degree 1}}, :allow-parallel? false, :undirected? true, :attrs {}, :cached-hash #object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x16da1abc {:status :ready, :val -1}]}
   ```

---

I suspect the NPE was because you had installed ubergraph somehow, but didn't allow it to automatically resolve its dependencies. When it tried to run `import-vals`, one of the libraries it depends on wasn't found, and it threw a fit.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but unfortunately, I still run into the NPE on the same exact spot.
```but didn't allow it to automatically resolve its dependencies```
Do you have an idea about how to solve this? But thank you for the simplified tutorial, this has already helped me get better at clojure.

Comment: @heathcliff Try running `lein clean`, or manually removing the files you had manually installed previously, then trying what I wrote again. It may not try to resolve the discrepancies if it sees that you already have ubergraph.

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled **everything**, and it worked! The NPE is gone and lein returned the the graph as code. Thanks for your help this far. Now, for the last part, I want proto-repl to return a generated graph. But after running the new project on the repl, it simply returns nothing, althhough it works in the terminal as described above.

Comment: Are you saying typing `(uber/graph [:a :b] [:a :c] [:b :d]))` in the REPL doesn't do anything? And I've never used Proto-repl, so there may be some quirk of it I don't know.

Comment: Typing ```(uber/pprint graph1)``` as mentioned on the github returns ```Syntax error compiling at (form-init3482870938599296850.clj:1:1).
No such namespace: uber``` The core.clj does not seem to load.

Comment: @heathcliff Again, I haven't used Proto, but in Cursive's REPL, you need to explicitly tell it what namespace to operate in. Try `(in-ns your.core.here)` in the REPL first. There is potetially even a key combo in your IDE for this (in IntelliJ, it's `ctrl+shift+L`).

Comment: Describing the namespace and graph individually in the repl, not the core, worked surprisingly! I recieve the expected output from ubergraph, but I can't figure out why it won't work in the core.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *Describing the namespace and graph individually in the repl, not the core, worked*. You need to change the current namespace of the REPL to the core before you can use ubergraph `require`d in the core.

Comment: Silly me put in the wrong command the whole time. It workjs now and I understand how. Thanks!